# Serialization in .NET - deserialization in Android

Tags: android, .net, serialization, deserialization

is there any way how to be able to serialize object in .NET and deserialize it in Android APK? I have tried WOX, but it is available only for pure Java (Android misses some imports). Is could be some custom serialization, but how to write it?

Thanks

Comment: What sort of objects do you want to serialize? Are they big?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is XML serialization. Takes more space than binary but being open you can do all you need to do on the Android side.

Comment: and how to do binary serialization via streams? Could it be a good approach?

Comment: No because .net default serializer using binaryFormatter is .Net specific. XML is the best option in cross platform situations.

Comment: But, what if I don't use binaryFormatter, which is .NET specific, and use only primitive datatypes?

Comment: Primitive datatypes... which are .net specific as streams are... a .net datetime is NOT a java datetime and XML with or without SOAP is the glue you need in the between

Answer (score 1):

I don't know .NET but I'm sure there is a way to serialize .NET objects to JSON, just googled this: http://json.codeplex.com/ There are also libs for JSON for Android. Here is an example of parsing a JSON object on Android: http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/

Comment: I have tried JSON, but now I would like to know, how to write some custom serialization/deserialization via streams (server serializes it, sends it as a stream via HTTP to Android and Android client deserializes it as a stream)